# How can I prevent or mitigate pybel erroneous addition of hydrogens to a CSO3 group

Tags: python, jupyter, openbabel, pybel

I read a PDB with a CSO3 group into pybel (The example was edited in Maestro Schrodinger to obscure the original chemistry). Note that since I use a lot of non natural amino acids and other molecule building blocks the amino acid name is inaccurate but easily read by Pymol and Schrodinger. Schrodinger also adds implicit hydrogens without the error! here is an original example:

```
TITLE     FullModel_2569-std-man
REMARK   4      COMPLIES WITH FORMAT V. 3.0, 1-DEC-2006
REMARK 888
REMARK 888 WRITTEN BY MAESTRO (A PRODUCT OF SCHRODINGER, LLC)
ATOM      1  N   ALA X   1      17.799  25.136  52.626  1.00 16.34           N1+
ATOM      2  CA  ALA X   1      16.591  25.195  51.764  1.00 16.34           C  
ATOM      3  C   ALA X   1      16.975  24.592  50.433  1.00 16.34           C  
ATOM      4  O   ALA X   1      17.063  23.378  50.330  1.00 16.34           O  
ATOM      5  N   ALA X   2      17.423  25.444  49.499  1.00  6.89           N  
ATOM      6  CA  ALA X   2      18.667  25.160  48.776  1.00  6.89           C  
ATOM      7  C   ALA X   2      19.807  25.237  49.806  1.00  6.89           C  
ATOM      8  O   ALA X   2      19.691  26.012  50.771  1.00  6.89           O  
ATOM      9  N   ALA X   3      20.783  24.323  49.735  1.00 10.36           N  
ATOM     10  CA  ALA X   3      21.710  24.047  50.849  1.00 10.36           C  
ATOM     11  C   ALA X   3      20.940  23.401  52.024  1.00 10.36           C  
ATOM     12  O   ALA X   3      19.722  23.200  51.950  1.00 10.36           O  
ATOM     13  CB  ALA X   3      22.871  23.144  50.393  1.00 10.36           C  
ATOM     14  SG  ALA X   3      24.414  23.586  51.244  1.00 20.00           S  
ATOM     15  OD1 ALA X   3      24.591  24.986  50.847  1.00 20.00           O1-
ATOM     16  OD2 ALA X   3      24.087  23.405  52.666  1.00 20.00           O  
ATOM     17  OD3 ALA X   3      25.366  22.624  50.685  1.00 20.00           O  
ATOM     18  N   ASP X   4      21.584  23.207  53.175  1.00 21.55           N  
ATOM     19  CA  ASP X   4      20.963  22.850  54.454  1.00 21.55           C  
ATOM     20  C   ASP X   4      19.873  23.860  54.847  1.00 21.55           C  
ATOM     21  O   ASP X   4      18.792  23.497  55.298  1.00 21.55           O  
ATOM     22  N   ARG X   5      20.063  25.132  54.464  1.00 29.63           N  
ATOM     23  CA  ARG X   5      19.068  26.199  54.538  1.00 29.63           C  
ATOM     24  C   ARG X   5      17.759  25.922  53.771  1.00 29.63           C  
ATOM     25  O   ARG X   5      16.712  26.441  54.157  1.00 29.63           O  
TER      26      ARG X   5
CONECT   13   14
CONECT   14   13   15   16   17
CONECT   14   16   17
CONECT   15   14
CONECT   16   14
CONECT   16   14
CONECT   17   14
CONECT   17   14
END
```

I ingest the PDB using the function below [it has to be a PDB and not mol2 or sdf because the original is PDB]

```
def pep_to_formats(data_path, mol_name, add_hydrogen=True):
        base = f"{data_path}/data/{mol_name}/{mol_name}"
    
        pep_pdb = f"{base}.pdb"
        std_pdb = f"{base}-std.pdb"
        babel_pdbh = f"{base}-babelh.pdb"
        babel_sdfh = f"{base}-babelh.sdf"
        babel_mol2h = f"{base}-babelh.mol2"
        babel_smileh = f"{base}-babelh.smile"
        babel_smilesh = f"{base}-babelh.smiles"
    
        ##input pepticom chemical expansion pdb file output and output standard hydrogenated pdb file
        babel_mol = pb.readfile(format="pdb", filename=std_pdb).__next__()
    
        if add_hydrogen:
            babel_mol.addh()  # add Hs for 3D
        # dd.make3D()
        babel_mol.write(format='pdb', filename=babel_pdbh, overwrite=True)
        babel_mol.write("sdf", babel_sdfh, True)
        babel_mol.write("mol2", babel_mol2h, True)
        babel_mol.write("smi", babel_smileh, True)
        babel_mol.write("smiles", babel_smilesh, True)
    
        return babel_mol, base
```

When I add hydrogens the output SDF adds hydrogens to one of the oxygens and the sulfur. clearly a mistake.

[image: mol depiction from jupyter]

Here is the resulting SDF

```
/Users/gideonbar/devel/pep-chem/md_python/data/FullModel_2569-std-man/FullModel_2569-std-man-std.pdb
 OpenBabel02022411333D

 43 43  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0999 V2000
   17.7990   25.1360   52.6260 N   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   16.5910   25.1950   51.7640 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   16.9750   24.5920   50.4330 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   17.0630   23.3780   50.3300 O   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   17.4230   25.4440   49.4990 N   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   18.6670   25.1600   48.7760 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   19.8070   25.2370   49.8060 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   19.6910   26.0120   50.7710 O   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   20.7830   24.3230   49.7350 N   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   21.7100   24.0470   50.8490 C   0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   20.9400   23.4010   52.0240 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   19.7220   23.2000   51.9500 O   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   22.8710   23.1440   50.3930 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   24.4140   23.5860   51.2440 S   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   24.5910   24.9860   50.8470 O   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   24.0870   23.4050   52.6660 O   0  5  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   25.3660   22.6240   50.6850 O   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   21.5840   23.2070   53.1750 N   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   20.9630   22.8500   54.4540 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   19.8730   23.8600   54.8470 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   18.7920   23.4970   55.2980 O   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   20.0630   25.1320   54.4640 N   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   19.0680   26.1990   54.5380 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   17.7590   25.9220   53.7710 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   16.7120   26.4410   54.1570 O   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   18.5772   24.5766   52.4008 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   16.2814   26.2108   51.6327 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   15.7766   24.6608   52.2070 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   16.9149   26.2630   49.2980 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   18.8183   25.8854   48.0041 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   18.6312   24.1954   48.3143 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   20.8868   23.8113   48.9004 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   22.1321   24.9731   51.1792 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   23.0086   23.2573   49.3380 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   22.6282   22.1299   50.6330 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   24.6600   24.5520   50.3188 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   25.3568   21.8133   51.2175 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   22.5627   23.3128   53.1652 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   21.7153   22.8355   55.2147 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   20.5093   21.8863   54.3517 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   20.9483   25.3660   54.1024 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   19.5055   27.0896   54.1376 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   18.7981   26.2859   55.5697 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  1  2  1  0  0  0  0
  1 24  1  0  0  0  0
  1 26  1  0  0  0  0
  2  3  1  0  0  0  0
  2 27  1  0  0  0  0
  2 28  1  0  0  0  0
  3  4  2  0  0  0  0
  3  5  1  0  0  0  0
  5  6  1  0  0  0  0
  5 29  1  0  0  0  0
  6  7  1  0  0  0  0
  6 30  1  0  0  0  0
  6 31  1  0  0  0  0
  7  8  2  0  0  0  0
  7  9  1  0  0  0  0
  9 10  1  0  0  0  0
  9 32  1  0  0  0  0
 10 11  1  0  0  0  0
 10 13  1  0  0  0  0
 10 33  1  1  0  0  0
 11 12  2  0  0  0  0
 11 18  1  0  0  0  0
 13 14  1  0  0  0  0
 13 34  1  0  0  0  0
 13 35  1  0  0  0  0
 14 15  2  0  0  0  0
 14 16  1  0  0  0  0
 14 36  1  0  0  0  0
 17 14  1  0  0  0  0
 17 37  1  0  0  0  0
 18 19  1  0  0  0  0
 18 38  1  0  0  0  0
 19 20  1  0  0  0  0
 19 39  1  0  0  0  0
 19 40  1  0  0  0  0
 20 21  2  0  0  0  0
 20 22  1  0  0  0  0
 22 23  1  0  0  0  0
 22 41  1  0  0  0  0
 23 24  1  0  0  0  0
 23 42  1  0  0  0  0
 23 43  1  0  0  0  0
 24 25  2  0  0  0  0
M  CHG  1  16  -1
M  END
$$$$
```

[image: babel SDF hydrogens]

[image: information about the bond distances and how I map them]

In my code I artificially add double bonds to two of the sulfur oxygen bonds in the PDB, because PDB doesn't capture resonance.

How can I prevent this or just delete the hydrogens. I tried

```
for neighbour_atom in ob.OBAtomAtomIter(at):
    
    atom_type = neighbour_atom.GetType()
    bond = at.GetBond(neighbour_atom)
    neighbour_index = bond.GetNbrAtomIdx(at)

    print(bond.GetLength())
    # print(bond.GetBondOrder())
    print(neighbour_index)
    # print(bond.IsAromatic())
    # print(bond.IsInRing())
    # print(bond.IsRotor())
    # print(bond.IsAmide())
    
    print(atom_type)
    if atom_type == 'H':

        pass
        # at.GetParent().DeleteAtom(neighbour_atom)
        mol.OBMol.DeleteAtom(neighbour_atom)
```

The code freezes

I converted it to a script and received this error:

```
Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11:SIGSEGV)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to remove hydrogen bonds after adding hydrogens:

```
# mol = next(pb.readfile("sdf", babel_sdfh)) # (readfile is described below)
mol = next(pb.readfile("pdb", std_pdb)) # (readfile is described below)
print(mol.molwt)
print(len(mol.atoms))
#%%
# dir(mol.OBMol)
#%%
print(f'num atoms: {mol.OBMol.NumAtoms()}')
print(f'mol.molwt: {mol.molwt}')
#%%
mol.OBMol.AddHydrogens()
#%%
print(f'num atoms: {mol.OBMol.NumAtoms()}')
print(f'mol.molwt: {mol.molwt}')
#%%
sulfur_atom = mol.OBMol.GetAtom(23)
#%%
sulfur_atom.GetType()
#%%
def remove_atom_hydrogens(mol_to_sheer, atom_to_sheer, adjacent_atoms=None, adjacent_atom_types=None):

    for neighbour_atom in ob.OBAtomAtomIter(atom_to_sheer):

        atom_type = neighbour_atom.GetType()
        bond = atom_to_sheer.GetBond(neighbour_atom)
        neighbour_index = bond.GetNbrAtomIdx(atom_to_sheer)

        bl = bond.GetLength()
        # print(bond.GetBondOrder())
        
        # print(bond.IsAromatic())
        # print(bond.IsInRing())
        # print(bond.IsRotor())
        # print(bond.IsAmide())

        print(f'neighbour_index: {neighbour_index} atom_type: {atom_type} bond length: {bl}')
        if atom_type[0] == 'H':

            # pass
            # at.GetParent().DeleteAtom(neighbour_atom)
            mol_to_sheer.OBMol.DeleteBond(bond)
            mol_to_sheer.OBMol.DeleteAtom(neighbour_atom)

        if adjacent_atoms is not None and adjacent_atom_types:
            if atom_type[0] in adjacent_atom_types:
                adjacent_atoms.append(neighbour_atom)


    return adjacent_atoms

adjacent_oxygens = remove_atom_hydrogens(mol, sulfur_atom, [], ['O'])
print(f'mol.OBMol.NumAtoms(): {mol.OBMol.NumAtoms()}')

for oxy in adjacent_oxygens:
    remove_atom_hydrogens(mol, oxy)

mol.OBMol.NumAtoms()
#%%
mol_name
#%%
mol
#%%
mol.OBMol.NumAtoms()
#%%
mol.write("sdf", babel_sdfh1, True)
```

I will be glad to see if there is a way to set ip the input PDB more correctly or add the hydrogens with better precision.